# Node axios don't save response in variable however it prints it in console

Tags: node.js, axios

I making API request to NewsAPI.org in node, If I simply use console log the response gets printed. Now I want it to return it in a var 'news' and it doesn't return it. Also I made the function return in 'updatedNews' still not working.

So the data is returned in console log but not saved in 'var'.

```
var news = 'news';

async function getNews() {
  var responseNews = await axios
    .get(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=key"
    )
    .then( response =>  news = response.data.articles );
    return responseNews;
}

var updatedNews = getNews()
console.log(news)
console.log(updatedNews)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with your code...

1. The response that comes back is an array of objects and not a string.
2. That is not how async / await works etc. etc..

This should work:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getNews() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=key',
  );

  const news = response.data.articles;
  console.log(news);
}

getNews();
```

Comment: I approved your answer as I think it shorter approach to make the request, I will read more about sync and async in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`var updatedNews = getNews()`

Here your making async call and in the next line your expecting the result. But here async call is not being resolved yet. The way we can achieve this is updated below.
here is the update code for same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    var news = ""

    function f() {
      return axios
        .get(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
        )
        .then(response => response.data.title);
    }

    f().then(news => console.log(news));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```